# How can i subtract date and time in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have create one document with date and time

```
use testing
db.test.insert({employee : 1, DateColumn1: new Date(), DateColumn2: new Date()})
```

After created the document, i have update DateColumn2 after 5 mins.

```
db.test.update({employee : 1}, {$set : {DateColumn2: new Date()}})
```

i tried this command to subtract the DateColumn2-DateColumn1 but it is showing numberlong format.

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project :{employee : 1, dateDifference: {$subtract: ["$DateColumn2","$DateColumn1"]}}}])
```

I need date and time format to display

Comment: the numberlong format is the difference between your two dates, in milliseconds. There's no proper way to convert it to hour, min, sec (using toDate() can do the job, as long as dateDifference doesn't exceed 24h00, but can generate some headaches instead). [Check this](http://blog.mmast.net/mongodb-seconds-to-minutes) to have an idea of how convert to formatted hh:mm:ss

Comment: @matthPen thanks for the reply. can i subtract at-least time without date, because in my project I have stored login time and logout time, then how should i know the exact working time(hh:mm:ss). please help me the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateDifference: {
        $subtract: [
          "$DateColumn2",
          "$DateColumn1"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      diffInSec: {
        $divide: [
          "$dateDifference",
          1000
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      hours: {
        $floor: {
          $divide: [
            "$diffInSec",
            3600
          ]
        }
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      remainingSeconds: {
        $subtract: [
          "$diffInSec",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$hours",
              3600
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      minutes: {
        $floor: {
          $divide: [
            "$remainingSeconds",
            60
          ]
        }
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      remainingSeconds: {
        $subtract: [
          "$remainingSeconds",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$minutes",
              60
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y1wkPphZJLX)

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. I have one more query. Can i store only time(hh:mm:ss) in mongodb. currently we are using new Date() command, but it was stored including date and time. I need only time store command. please help with the solution

Comment: how can i store time in hh:mm:ss format in mongodb?